# Omit specific Split Raster Output

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

When I use the ArcGIS Split Raster tool with a specified output size, I get rasters that are that size or smaller. Given an arbitrarily shaped raster, is there a way to extract *only* square rasters that are entirely contained within the original raster?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: Are you open to a python solution?